# VSCode doesn't step-in on brakepoints (PHP 7.3 Xdebug 3 in a Docker container)

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

From the attached log I can see that **connection was established** and breakpoints are recognized properly but **VSCode will not step in**.

Don't know how to properly "translate" Xdebug log tags `hit_count`, `hit_value`, `exception -x *` in  sections `i 7` - `i 8` of xdebug.log.

Any help with the above issue will be greatly appreciated. It will help as well to get link to more details about Xdebug log tags.

Running complete setup on CentOS 8 with VSCode and browser (Firefox and Chrome both most recent as of march 2021) on base and PHP, MySQL, webserver in containers on the same PC.

Bellow are:

- VSCode about
- content of xdebug.ini
- content of launch.json
- sample PHP application that is used for testing
- Xdebug log content

#### VSCode on Centos 8 (about)

```
Version: 1.54.3
Commit: xxx
Date: 2021-03-15T10:55:24.277Z
Electron: 11.3.0
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64
```

#### xdebug.ini (php 7.3 docker with Xdebug v3.03)

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

#### launch.json content

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "log" : true,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "hostname": "172.17.0.1",
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**/*.php"
        ],
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_children": 10000,
            "max_data": 10000,
            "show_hidden": 1
        }
    } 
]
```

#### Sample application phpinfo.php:

```
<?php
   $test_var="test";
   echo $test_var;
   phpinfo();
?>
```

#### xdebug.log

```
bash-5.1$ cat /tmp/xdebug.log 
[8] Log opened at 2021-03-23 02:29:39.840314
[8] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.17.0.1:9003.
[8] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.17.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[8] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/public/phpinfo.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.27" protocol_version="1.0" appid="8" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.0.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[8] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n max_children -v 10000
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_data -v 10000
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n show_hidden -v 1
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 4
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="4"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///var/www/html/www/public/phpinfo.php -n 2
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="80001"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 6
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="6"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///var/www/html/www/public/phpinfo.php" lineno="2" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="80001"></breakpoint></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 7
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="7"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///var/www/html/www/public/phpinfo.php" lineno="2" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="80001"></breakpoint></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t exception -x *
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="80002"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- run -i 9
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="9" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[8] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 10
[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="10" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[8] Log closed at 2021-03-23 02:29:39.872178
```

Comment: Found the problem.

Comment: Found the problem, from the attached log was clear that xdebug makes connection to remote IDE (vscode) and gets all proper information about breakpoints, what was not visible was that launch,json "pathMappings" was incorrect. Changing "pathMappings" value to "pathMapings":{"/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/www") fix the problem.